# Selecting characters and the whole line with regex

Tags: regex

I have many lines in my .csv file that have have characters like the following

@@ -135,7 +151,6 @@

that I would like to delete along with the line it is on too. I thought this would work

```
\@.*\@$
```

but this regex is only select just the characters and that is it. How would I adjust this to select the characters and the line too?

Comment: So you mean to select a line that would look something like this: `abc@@ -135,7 +151,6 @@ def`?

Comment: no a line that looks like this: @@ -135,7 +151,6 @@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are whitespaces after the last @, it will fail. So compensate for that,

```
\@.*\@.*$
```

I'm wondering what the `.` after `*` is for. Try if this works.

Try it without $ as it may check for the end of the document. Also expected a newline after the last @.

```
\@.*\@\n
```

Comment: that was a mistake, but the regex you suggest is only still just selecting the characters and not the characters and the line too

Comment: edited my answer, it should remove any line starting with @ and ends with @ and a newline.